# How to integrate Stencil Web Components in NextJS (implementing SSR not CSR)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, web-component, stenciljs

I have created Stencil web components which are published on NPM. Now I have installed that package in NextJS. I have done Client Side Serving of those stencilJS components in Next JS shown below:
[image]

Now I want to achieve (SSR) server side rendering of the same stencil web component in next js. How can I achieve that. There is no doc relevant to this.

Comment: If I may ask, why not use the Stencil compiler itself? Stencil isn't designed to be built using webpack (even with plugins such as ts-loader). Instead, compiling a Stencil project requires the Stencil compile.

If you're just getting started with Stencil, I recommend spinning up a project with the [create-stencil CLI](https://github.com/ionic-team/create-stencil). There's a walkthrough of how to use it on the [Stencil site here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/getting-started)

Comment: @RyanWaskiewicz actually I am comparing the build size of React, Lit.dev & Stencil. So I have to use same bundler

Comment: I see - unfortunately, that likely won't work. Stencil is an all-in-one compiler/toolchain. It includes the TS compiler and bundler (rollup).  It's not designed to use Webpack/ts-loader etc. If comparing bundle sizes is your end goal (all other things being equal), I'd encourage you to use Stencil's tooling for the Stencil aspect of your investigation, and compare its output to React & Lit with whatever tooling you end up using for those. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

add it inside a `useEffect` works.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    defineCustomElements(window, {
      resourcesUrl: "/basepath-if-necessary"
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("components loaded");
    });
  }, []);
```